# Post trough iframe curl and parse html response

Tags: php, curl

I have a question but trough reading docs Im not able to understand rightly.
With cURL am I able to send a request like  Post action="www.mywebpagescript.com" data="Hello" and retrieve the html response and process it?

Like I have a page called "www.mysweethome.com/Home.php" and on home.php an iframe of 1000px x 1000px curls "www.littledollsleeping.com/validator.php and post content to validator.php using im logged in with cookie, and parse the response from validator.php, would be possible?